# showing one data from the same data in one column

Tags: mysql

I have database like this:

**database**
[image]

Can you help me to print **teamRegion** like this:

Spain

England

Germany

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select DISTINCT teamRegion from Table_name;
```

Or

```
Select teamRegion from Table_name GROUP BY teamRegion;
```

Comment: Welcome!! @LOKI

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Select `teamRegion` from `tableName` group by `teamRegion`;
```